# WebAPI POST method arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI project. There is a post action in a certain controller that takes in an argument [FromBody]. The argument is received fine when I debug the project locally, but when I publish the same project, the argument received is null. Same WebAPI project, same javascript client calling the action.

Javascript (jQuery) Request:

```
var myRequest = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: globalRoot + '/api/afternoonvisitcall',
            data: AfternoonVisitCalls,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (resultData) {
                // resultData is false (for Published application)
            },
            error: function (error) {

            }
        });
```

CS Controller:

```
public class AfternoonVisitCallController : ApiController
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Get(){...}
   public object Get(string id){...}
   public bool Post([FromBody]VisitList AfternoonVisitCalls)
   {
        if (AfternoonVisitCalls != null)
        {
            Logger.Log("In POST api/afternoonvisitcall",
                         Logger.files.WebAPI_log,
                         " input arg AfternoonVisitCalls is NOT null");

            return AfternoonVisitCalls.SaveAfternoonListWithSamples();
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Log("In POST api/afternoonvisitcall",
                         Logger.files.WebAPI_log,
                         " input arg AfternoonVisitCalls is NULL");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

CS RouteConfig.cs file:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

CS WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "myRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{date}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

There is even other post action in other controller and it works fine. I am not sure why this is, I am running out of ideas. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to find an answer without more information. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It seems that there is a problem deserializing the body data. How looks the class `VisitList`? I am not sure, but it should be possible, for testing,  to change the type of the parameter of the `Post` method to `String`. Then you should see what data is send and how it is formatted.

Comment: Publish to where? You tagged IIS6. It's end-of-life, not supported. Upgrade your webserver.

Comment: @ADyson I wish I can, its a production server, I have no say in the matter

Answer (score 0):

It worked! I am not sure how, but I set the 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"  and the data as data: JSON.stringify(avc_obj), instead of the object itself, in the AJAX request.